# Kendo UI Charts - Diplay text instead of value in yAxis labels

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Is there any way to display a label other than the value in the Value Axis in Kendo Chart?

What I want is the right image's labels instead of the left one's (the original).

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>

// these are the labels I want to replace for the number values.
const yAxisLabels = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [
    {
      type: "line",
      data: [2, 3, 4]
    }
  ],
  valueAxis: {
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    majorUnit: 1
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is - templates are what you are looking for. However, from your question there is no way to help with exactly how to accomplish what you want since there is no code/or explanation of where your alternate values come from. That said, the following is one way to customize those labels.

Dojo example: https://dojo.telerik.com/OsuWirih

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [
    {
      type: "scatter",
      data: [ [1, 2] ]
    }
  ],
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      template: "X: #: value #"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

More info here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/yaxis.labels#yaxislabelstemplate

EDIT:

From your comment, I'm still not sure what is driving the A,B,C to replace values. Here is *one* way to accomplish it if the underlying values line up with the A, B, C... labels you want:

```
<script>
let dict = {0:'A',0.5:'B',1:'C',1.5:'D',2:'E',2.5:'F'};
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [
    {
      type: "scatter",
      data: [ [1, 2] ]
    }
  ],
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      template: "#: dict[value] #"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

and in a dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/EpElOFAy/2

Comment: Thanks, @G_P. I've added the code, with an array of labels (const yAxisLabels). What I want to do is to replace the values (1, 2, 3...) with the labels (A, B, C...)

Comment: Added another example... hope it helps